# Can I prevent notifications from being forwarded to my watch during Do Not Disturb?

Tags: notifications, bluetooth, google-pixel-3-xl

I have a Pixel 3 phone running Android 11, paired with a Garmin Venu watch. The Pixel can forward notifications to my watch via Bluetooth, with per-app notification controls specified in the Garmin connect app. I've noticed that whenever I set my phone on Do Not Disturb, I still get notifications forwarded to my watch. Is there a way on the phone to prevent notifications from being forwarded to my watch while in DND?

Comment: you can freeze the app or remove the notification access of the app while in dnd mode. Will that be a problem in anyway?

Comment: @Aayush, I'd prefer to do it globally for all apps.

Comment: No i mean there will be an app of Smart watch installed on your phone right?(that connect app maybe.. Is that it?) Which has notification access and it send the notifications to your smartwatch.

Comment: I was saying that you can just freeze the "Garmin connect app" while in dnd mode and unfreeze it when dnd is off

Comment: @Aayush, oh yes, that should work. Freezing the Garmin Connect App.Thanks!

Comment: So.. should i post an answer or.. you can do it yourself?

Comment: @Aayush, go for it.